# INNER JOIN LIMIT 1 WITH USING PAGINATION

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How do i limit inner join to 1 with order by DESC on this part

> ```
> INNER JOIN comments ON thread.t=comments.comment_id
> ```

this is my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf7de8400327b98631d2f6d9b23084b5

[image: Thread Table]

[image: Comments Table]

[image: Result]

look at result output there is the problem on duplicate content because of comments (need to limit 1) @M Khalid Junaid

Comment: Posting code using external links isn't very helpful. It would be preferable if you could post the whole code in your question along with some sample input data and corresponding result set.

Comment: cant post whole code here because of error red box.. idk why

Comment: Try reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) post for instructions on how to post code as well formatted text.

Comment: *with order by DESC* of what ?

Comment: order by id from comments

Comment: Can you also provide your table definitions. `thread.t=comments.comment_id` looks strange to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join to your comments table to pick the recent comment only for each post

```
SELECT 
  t.t_dp,
  t.t,
  t.t_id,
  t.tittle,
  t.t_username,
  t.t_date_posting,
  t.views,
  c.comments,
  c.comment_time,
  c.comment_id,
  c.c 
FROM
  thread t 
  INNER JOIN comments c 
    ON t.t = c.comment_id 
  LEFT JOIN comments c1 
    ON c.comment_id = c1.comment_id 
    AND c.id < c1.id 
WHERE t.t_type = '02' 
  AND c1.id IS NULL 
LIMIT @start_from, @results_per_page
```

Also you are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` which makes no sense,  In which order limit applies on records.

Comment: sir extra question.. i think i have problem with thread because it only show if thread have comment but when comments not found thread not show on query

Comment: @Starde change `INNER` to `LEFT` join